# Collapsible header for every <apex:pageBlockTable> records. Is it possible?

Tags: pageblocktable, repeat, header-bar

I wanted to have a collapsible header for each records (100, 50, 10 in screenshot) that the pageblocktable generates for order lines. For now there is just 1 collapsible header for all order lines. I have tried for the following code. I added repeat tag inside pageblocktable. It only repeats the values equal to the number of records.

```
 <apex:page standardcontroller="orders__c" extensions="OrderTrackingList" sidebar="true" title="Orders" showHeader="true">
<!--Order details-->
<apex:sectionheader title="Order" subtitle="Detail"/>
<!--   <apex:form style="align-center:center;"> -->
     <apex:pageBlock >                   
         <apex:repeat value="{!StartHere}" var="gp">                              
             <apex:pageblocksection title="Order Details" showheader="true" collapsible="true" columns="2">
                  <apex:outputText value="{!gp.acc.Orders__c}" />
                  <apex:outputText value="{!gp.acc.number_of_line_items__c}" label="Total Materials"/>
                  <apex:outputText value="{!gp.acc.account__r.name}"/>
                  <apex:outputText value="{!gp.acc.CreatedDate}"/>
             </apex:pageblocksection>     

            <apex:pageblocksection title="Order Lines" showheader="true" collapsible="true" columns="1">
              <apex:repeat value  value="{!gp.con}" var="p" >
              <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!gp.con}" var="p" border="9">         

                <apex:column colspan="7"> 
                    <apex:facet name="header">#</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLink value="/{!p.id}"><apex:outputText value="{!p.Name}"/></apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                 <apex:column >
                     <apex:facet name="header">Quantity</apex:facet>
                     <apex:outputText value="{!p.quantity_ordered__c}"/>
                 </apex:column>                                          
                 <apex:column >
                     <apex:facet name="header">Status</apex:facet>
                     <apex:outputText value="{!p.status__c}"/>
                 </apex:column>
                </apex: pageblocktable>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
             </apex:pageblocksection>

         </apex:repeat>             
         </apex:pageBlock>

<!-- </apex:form>  -->
</apex:page>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: Added Screenshot below[image: .]

Comment: screen shot of what you are trying to do would be helpful

Comment: @crop1645 Thanks for the suggestion. Added screenshot!

Comment: @MnZ - Try out the Datatables library - great stuff. Here is a link to collapsable groups: http://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/collapsibleGroups.html - Datatables is at http://datatables.net

Comment: @MnZ you may have to look into Jquery AFAIK you cannot do this using pure VF route

Comment: You could build it through pure Visualforce. I still don't know exactly where the OP is going with this, but it looks like a simple nested loop should do it.

Comment: Thanks rao and eric. @sfdcfox I do know this makes the screen very clumsy, client has this weird requirement, so for now I'm exploring jquery.

Comment: It's harder to get the right "look and feel" of Salesforce with jQuery, but you'll get better performance client-side, so the tradeoff is probably worth it. jQuery isn't your only option though, so I'd shop around for alternatives, too. In fact, in most cases, you can get 400% performance or more simply by writing your own JavaScript instead of depending on a library (see http://vanilla-js.com/ for various examples; while the site is a joke, the advice it gives isn't).